# Nikon D500 is over exposing photos in burst mode

Tags: nikon

While using my D500 in burst mode, and upon review of the photos it appears that every other third photo or so is blown out (over exposed). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have exposure bracketing turned on?

Comment: What lens are you using? Please include the full model name including any letters/numbers before and after the focal length(s) and max aperture.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, this sounds like you have exposure bracketing enabled. It's set for 3-shot bracketing, so that your first and 2nd shots are under- or neutrally-exposed (the order and amount of exposure compensation is depending upon your settings), and the 3rd shot is over-exposed.

Check your settings ([refer to the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1101827/Nikon-D500.html?page=173#manual)) and make sure bracketing is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

What aperture value are you using? I cannot be sure about your case but I once had a lens with wobbly aperture link which would would result almost in a stop of difference.